# Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\jars-9\196b729407d7fbb2907378f4b4c34b5a\kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

This is my first real react-native project. I was running the project with expo go without any issues. And then to add google oauth I had to expo eject the project. After ejecting(now a bare react-native project) I get this error..(I got few errors which I fixed. I'm stuck with this.)

When I run yarn android build fails with this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\jars-9\196b729407d7fbb2907378f4b4c34b5a\kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I tried cleaning gradle cache, build folder and they didn't work. Appreciate if someone can give some pointers. If you want to see build.gradle,manifest files let me know in comments I will update the question.

Answer (score 2):

[same problem (link image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5ToM.png)

first, have you checked your setup :

`npx react-native doctor`

link https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

if all setup correct, have you tried to repro after a fresh run

```
git clean -fdx
```

in your project?
if still happening, clean your Windows Gradle cache :

```
C:\Users\user\.gradle\
```

please check more info by leotm : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34295#issuecomment-1201269698

Comment: Actually it was a issue with expo 48 version.(https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21750) I downgraded expo version and it works now.

Comment: @ShehanDMG What is `expo`?

Comment: I used expo to create react native app